# Problems with displaying multi array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to display multi arrays.

```
public class apples {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int Tabela_Nr1[][] = {{8,9,10,11}, {12,13,14,15}};
        int Tabela_Nr2[][] = {{30,31,32,33}, {43},{4,5,6,}};

        System.out.println("To jest pierwsza tabela: ");
        wyswietl(Tabela_Nr1);

        System.out.println("To jest druga tabela: ");
        wyswietl(Tabela_Nr2);
    }

    public static void wyswietl(int x [][]){
        for (int row = 0; row < x.length; row++){
            for(int counter = 0; counter < x[row].length; counter++);
                System.out.print(x[row][counter] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Debugger tells me that variable counter is not declare, but it is in "for" loop... 
What is the cuz of the problem ?

Console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
counter cannot be resolved to a variable

at apples.wyswietl(apples.java:15)
at apples.main(apples.java:8)
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the extra semi colon :

```
for (int row=0;row<x.length;row++){
    for(int counter=0;counter<x[row].length;counter++); //<-- here
        System.out.print(x[row][counter]+"\t");
```

This semi colon end the inner loop, which means the print statement is outside the loop, where `counter` is unknown.

I think that your `System.out.println();` is also wrongly placed. You probably want to place it after each row :

```
public static void wyswietl(int x[][]){
    for (int row=0;row<x.length;row++) {
        for(int counter=0;counter<x[row].length;counter++) {
            System.out.print(x[row][counter]+"\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`for(int counter=0;counter<x[row].length;counter++);` --> remove the `;` and it will work just fine :)

BTW you might also want to look into --> `Arrays.deepToString()` which displays *multi-dimensional* arrays.

Comment: Thanks, my bad. Stupid mistake